# How do you print the underscore in a zebra label?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I’m printing a parameter returned from a query that’s a string of letters and underscores.

The label prints just the letters without the underscores, and I’m not sure how to fix it.

```
^FD<String>^FS
^FH^FD<String>^FS

Thank you very much.

(Removing the FH Only reads to the first underscore.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `^FH` command without parameter defaults to underscore as the hexidecimal escape character.  Either remove the `^FH` or specify a different escape character like backslash using `^FH\^FD<String>^FS`.